# How to mark data as anomalies based on specific condition in each interval

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-slicing

I try to search for this problem many places and couldn't find the right tools.

I have a simple time series data,

```
print(anom)
```

```
0        0
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        0
        ..
52777    1
52778    1
52779    0
52780    1
```

For any sequence of data that is = 1 and span over (for example 1000 time instances). I want to mark those as anomalies (true). Else they should be ignore (as false).

How do I achieve this with pandas or numpy?

I also want to plot those anomalies, with the colour red for example, how do we achieve that?

How do I mark those anomalies (values = 1 that expanse for around 1000 time instances) as red?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly clear which output you expect.
Yet, let's consider the following dataset similar to yours:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice([0,1], size=100, p=[0.7, 0.3]), name='anom')
```

```
0     1
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
     ..
95    0
96    1
97    1
98    0
99    1
Name: anom, Length: 100, dtype: int64
```

Looking like:

[image: input data]

#### filtering based on consecutive values

First we calculate the length of the stretches of 1s

```
length = s.groupby(((s-s.shift().fillna(0)).eq(1).cumsum()*s)).transform(len)*s
```

This works by identifying the first element of the stretches `(s-s.shift().fillna(0)).eq(1)` (the difference between one element and the precedent is 1 only in case of 1 preceded by 0, see graph #2 below). Then it makes increasing groups (graph #3) that group each stretch of 1s and the successive stretch of 0s. By multiplying by `s`, only the 1s are kept in the group (graph #4). Now we can group the data per stretch and calculate each one's length (graph #5). The 0s will be all part of one group, so finally, we remove the zeros by multiplying again by `s` (graph #6).

Here is the visual representation of the successive steps where `(…)` denotes the previous step in each graph:

[image: breakdown of stretches length calculation]

```
s_valid = s.loc[length<10]
s_anom = s.drop(s_valid.index)

ax = s_valid.plot(marker='o', ls='')
s_anom.plot(marker='o', ls='', ax=ax, color='r')
```

[image: line+dots]

```
ax = s.plot()
s_anom.plot(marker='o', ls='', ax=ax, color='r')
```

[image: line+dots]

other example with 7 as threshold:

[image: line+dots ; 7 as threshold]

#### original answer

---

You can easily convert to `bool` to get anomalies

```
>>> s.astype(bool)
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
      ...  
95    False
96     True
97     True
98    False
99     True
Name: anom, Length: 100, dtype: bool
```

Regarding the plot, depending on what you expect you can do:

```
s_valid = s.loc[~s.astype(bool)]
s_anom = s.loc[s.astype(bool)]

ax = s_valid.plot(marker='o', ls='')
s_anom.plot(marker='o', ls='', ax=ax, color='r')
```

output:

[image: data as dots anomalies in red]

```
s_anom = s.loc[s.astype(bool)]
ax = s.plot()
s_anom.plot(marker='o', ls='', ax=ax, color='r')
```

[image: data as lines anomalies as red dots]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but one more condition needs to specified, I want to mark as anomaly only if data is consecutively 1 in 90% of the 1000 sample window size. Otherwise, it is not anomaly. Would that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, no problem, see my updated answer. Here I used a smaller dataset with 10 consecutive 1s as a threshold.

Comment: Hi friend, just came back to this project, could you kindly explain me this funcion ```s.groupby(((s-s.shift().fillna(0)).eq(1).cumsum()*s)).transform(len)*s```

Comment: Sure, I added a paragraph to explain it. Let me know if this is unclear

Comment: Hey buddy, I've got your explanation and worked out in python notebook. It's all making sense now, how'd you get this approach? I have no idea where to find this intuition?

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

```
np.random.seed(1)
anom = pd.Series(np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[0.2, 0.8], size=10000))

print(anom)

0       1
1       1
2       0
3       1
4       0
       ..
9995    1
9996    1
9997    0
9998    0
9999    1
Length: 10000, dtype: int64
```

#### Solution

**Detection of anomalies**

```
m = anom == 1
c = anom[m].groupby((~m).cumsum()).transform('count')
a = c[c > 25].clip(upper=1) # Detection threshold=25
```

**Plotting the detected anomalies**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
bars = ax.bar(a.index, a, facecolor='red', edgecolor='red')
```

#### Result

[image]