# how to get max count of consecutive 1 in column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I Have one dataframe with column Flag1 in this, I want to check if in column flag value 1 occurs continuously for maximum times

Here is the dataframe and output format

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'flag':[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]}) 
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'max_count':[3]})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution with `pandas`

```
m = df['flag'].eq(1)
max(m[m].groupby((~m).cumsum()).sum())
```

#### Solution with `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

max(sum(g) for k, g in groupby(df['flag']) if k == 1)
```

##### Result

```
3
```

Comment: I like the itertools solution a lot ;)

Answer (score 3):

We can emulate [`itertools.groupby` style grouping using `df.shift` +`df.ne`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684028/12416453)

```
m = df['flag'].eq(1)
g = df['flag'].ne(df['flag'].shift()).cumsum()[m]

df[m].groupby(g).count().max()

# flag    3
# dtype: int64
```

Comment: I like this solution.  Upvoted.  Can we simplify the definition of `g` without selection by `[m]` if we are going to use `df[m]` in the last line of code ?

Comment: @SeaBean Thanks. Grouping array length should be equal to the length of `df`.

Answer (score 2):

I provided an answer to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68451953/16343464):

You can do:

```
s = df['flag']

(s.groupby(((s-s.shift().fillna(0)).eq(1).cumsum()*s))
  .transform(len)*s
).max()
```

output: `3`